# eBay API not returning anything (I think)

Tags: fetch, ebay-api

I am making use of the eBay API to do a keyword look up.  I tested my API string at https://robwu.nl/cors-anywhere.html.  I used the following string to test:

> http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=jonathan-wmjw-PRD-5262ede01-60b402b1&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&keywords=twix&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3

and clicked on the GET button and the API returns a valid response.

When I incorporate the API call into my fetch, I am not able to get the response data.  This is the code I am executing:

```
                console.log(url);
            const options = { method: 'GET' };                
            fetch( url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                if (response.status >= 400) 
                {
                    console.log("eBay returned bad status of: ", response.status);
                }
                return false;
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                console.log("second then");
                if (myJson == undefined) 
                {
                    console.log("myJson = undefined");
                    document.getElementById("errorDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("lblErrorText").innerHTML = "eBay was unable to find a match on " + decoded + ". That is the name our bar code service returned.  If you want, you can try entering a different product name for eBay to try.";            

                } 
                else 
                {     
                    console.log("then else");
                    //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
                    console.log(myJson);
                }
```

When I look in the developers tools under console, I see the following entries in the log:

[image]

The log entry that displays "false" is where I expected to be able to inspect the data returned by the API.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well you're specifically returning false from the first `.then()` which is then passed to the next `.then()`. Return the response instead.

Comment: Thats what I get for coding 24 hours straight.  Thank you so much.